# 2 column layout looping through MVC model c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm attempting to create a 2 column bootstrap layout with dynamic data coming from an MVC model, using Razor. Goal is to have unique data in each column until looping is complete. The following code repeats the same data in both columns.  What logic would I need in order to make this work

```
@{
int i=1;
foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="checkbox" checked="@item.Checked" />
            @item.Description
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="checkbox" checked="@item.Checked" />
            @item.Description
        </div>
    </div>
    i++;
}
```

}

Comment: `Goal is to have unique data` you copy and pasted your `<div class="col-md-6">`, how were you expecting to get unique data?

Comment: it's repeating the same data because the loop doesn't move to the next item until after the second column.  you need to loop over your item on each column.  keep track of the iteration with a counter. one loop displays when the iteration is "even" and the other when it's "odd".

Comment: Seems like messy approach. I would create a model that has what you need on each row, so you iterate and display columns in simple way.

Comment: @Jonesopolis that's the question I am asking...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to iterate your items over each column in order to get different items in each.  One way to do this is to track "even" and "odd" iterations and display items based on that.

```
<div class="row">
int cnt1 = 0;
foreach (var item in Model)
{
  if(cnt1 % 2 == 0) {
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="checkbox" checked="@item.Checked" />
        @item.Description
    </div>
  }
  cnt1++;
}
int cnt2 = 0;
foreach (var item in Model)
{
  if(cnt2 % 2 != 0) {
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="checkbox" checked="@item.Checked" />
        @item.Description
    </div>
  }
 cnt2++;
}
</div> //end row
```

Another way to achieve this would be to divide your items into 2 lists in the controller and iterate over list 1 for the first column and list 2 for the second column.

Comment: not quite working, I need to start the row in the first loop but finish it in the second, correct? My markup is behaving strangely

Comment: it's two independent loops.  so you're looping over your model twice.  each time, you display every other record.  the items  not displayed in the first loop are displayed in the second one.

Comment: I think you can using if else statement to reduce line of code.

Answer (score 2):

With respect to delvin carnate solution, you can even do it in a single foreach loop. It would be faster, because you iterating only once the loop.

```
  <div class="row">
        @{int a = 0; }
        @foreach (var auhtor in authors)
        {
            if (a % 2 == 0)
            {
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                @Html.ActionLink(auhtor, "Author", new { id = auhtor }, new { @class = "btn text-primary" })
            </div>
            }
            else
            {
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                @Html.ActionLink(auhtor, "Author", new { id = auhtor }, new { @class = "btn text-primary" })
            </div>
            }
            a++;
        }
    </div>
```

Comment: It working but need to custome. Thanks again @Shaahin for your ideas